# anguilla framework window.onload $messages not working like model

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme

When i open the page first time my $messages not working like model instead its showing like notification top right corner. But after i refresh (F5) same page its showing like model my messages. below code.

Ref:http://codedweapon.com/tag/messages/

```
loadmessage = function () {
    if($url.getQueryParam("tcm") == 64) {   

        question = $messages.registerQuestion("Do you love GUI Extensions?", null, true, true, { cancel: "Hate Them!", confirm: "Love Them!" });
        question.addEventListener("cancel", function (event) {
        return false;
        });
        question.addEventListener("confirm", function (event) { 
        return true;
        });

    }
}
window.onload = function(){
    loadmessage();
}
```

[image: Aftercloseandreopen]